# Posting model data from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am pretty new to MVC and I ran into some problems:

I have a view that has 2 foreach loops that displays data. Something like:

```
foreach(var item in Model.items){
using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName")){
<div>
@item.Info @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Id)
    foreach(var parameter in item.parameters){
    @parameter.Info @EditorFor(param => parameter.Value)
}
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
</div>
}
}
```

So far so good...
I want to allow a user to edit the parameter values in one of the items and press submit (can be a submit in each of the item-divs). I have tried many different ways to do this but everything is null when the controlleraction recieves the item except for the item.Id.

Is this just the wrong way of doing it or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post code for the form you are trying to submit

Comment: i have updated my code with the form

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` doesn't generate correct names for your inputs, so it isn't recognized by the model binder when you submit. You can go for `for` loops (which gives correct indexes), but i suggest you to use `EditorTemplates` :

In your main view :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items)
```

Assuming you `Items` property is a collection of `ItemModel` (replace it by the type you're using), you create an `EditorTemplate` (which has to be located in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder) that take an `ItemModel` as model :

```
@model ItemModel

@Model.Info @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parameters)
```

And assuming that `Parameters`' type is a collection of `ParameterModel` (again, use your real type), create another `EditorTemplate` (still located in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder) :

```
@model ParameterModel

@Model.Info @EditorFor(model => model.Value)
```

All your fields will be correctly named, allowing the model binder to fetch the right values when you submit your form.

Now, some more explanations about what's happening : a template (either `DisplayTemplate` or `EditorTemplate`, according to your needs) gives a representation of a specific model, which is reusable across all your views, and automatically called when you use `HtmlHelpers` (it works by convention, the template name must be the type name). ASP.NET MVC already have built-in templates, for types like `string`, `DateTime`, etc (that's why you get a checkbox when you use `@Html.Editor` or `@Html.EditorFor` with a `boolean` property).

When you use `@Html.EditorFor` with an `IEnumerable<ItemModel>`, it checks if an `EditorTemplate` named `ItemModel.cshtml` exists, and uses it to display each `ItemModel` in your collection. It correctly generates input fields in order to get values back when you submit. In this `EditorTemplate`, you display its properties, including `Parameters` which is also a collection of a complex type. Then again, it searches for an `EditorTemplate` called `ParameterModel.cshtml` (in this example), and uses it to display each parameter.

If no template is defined, it uses default template for object type, which only displays simple properties (like `string`, `int`...).

This powerful feature is useful to keep your code clear while allowing flexibility when you build your views. Remember that those templates have specific locations : either `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`), or `Views/{MyControllerName}/EditorTemplates` (`Views/{MyControllerName}/DisplayTemplates`).

Comment: Thank you for a very nice post! Will try it out.